# Salesforce Batch Resource Availability

Tags: batch

Is it possible, that if i schedule a batch at 9pm and salesforce does not have a resuorces to execute the batch till 12am and then the batch will be executed the next day, 00:01am the next day?

Answer (score 0):

In Salesforce, if you schedule a batch class to run at a specific time, it will not execute immediately at the scheduled time if there are no available resources. Instead, it will be queued for execution and will run as soon as resources become available.

If the batch is scheduled for 9 PM and Salesforce does not have resources available until 12 AM, the batch will be executed as soon as possible after 12 AM. The exact time at which it will run depends on the availability of resources and the order in which other scheduled jobs are processed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible for a scheduled batch job in Salesforce to be executed the next day if the system resources are not available to process it at the scheduled time. Salesforce's platform infrastructure manages the scheduling and execution of batch jobs based on available resources.

When you schedule a batch job, Salesforce will attempt to execute it as close to the specified schedule time as possible. However, if there is a high volume of jobs or limited resources available at the scheduled time, the execution may be delayed.

If the resources become available after the scheduled time (e.g., between 9 PM and 12 AM in your example), Salesforce will execute the batch job at the earliest available the resources. This could be at 12:01 AM the next day or any time when the resources are available.

Salesforce will execute the jobs according to the specified schedule, like system load, limits, and resource availability can impact the execution time but moreover ***its rare possibility of this kind of scenario until instance is down or any technical glitch from salesforce side so far***.